# Не могу вывести данные из firebase в angular 4

Tags: angular2, firebase, firebase-database

Есть приложение канбан доска, для ввода заданий беру из формы значения полей и создаю массив объектов`tasks:Tasks[];`

```
`onSubmit(){
  this.title = this.taskForm.value.title;
  this.priority = this.taskForm.value.priority;
  this.desc = this.taskForm.value.desc;
  this.tasks.push({
    priority:this.priority,
    title:this.title,
    desc:this.desc,
  })
this.serverService.storeTasks(this.tasks).subscribe();
}`
```

и отправляю их при помощи пост запроса:

```
storeTasks(tasks: Tasks[]){
  return this.http.post("https://kanban-board-3140a.firebaseio.com/data.json", tasks);
}`
```

Далее я хочу получить эти данные при помощи гет запроса

```
 getTasks(){
      return this.http.get("https://kanban-board 3140a.firebaseio.com/data.json").map(
        (resp: Response)=>{
          const data = resp.json();
          return data;
        }
      );
    }
```

Получить эти  данные и записать в массив tasks

```
  getTasks(){
    this.serverServices.getTasks().subscribe(
      (data)=>
        {this.task.push(data);
        console.log(this.task);}

    )
  }
```

И вывести в HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <h3>DO IT</h3><button (click)="getTasks()">  Do it</button>
  <div class="task-low" *ngFor="let task of task;let i = index">
  <p>{{task.title}}</p>
  <p>{{task.desc}}</p>
  </div>
```

Я хочу получить массив объектов но ничего не получается, *ngFor создает только один элемент, и он пустой. Также не могу понять как сохранять информацию в firebase, чтобы там был один массив с объектами, при каждом пост запросе firebase создает новый массив в data.json,[image: firebase data] пробовал пут и патч запросы тоже не помогает. Если вы можете помочь, буду очень благодарен